# Remove QR Code after being Scanned

Tags: ionic2, qr-code

I've tried reading the documents or search for other similar question to it in stackoverflow or online, but it's either I'm not googling correctly.I'm not sure how to remove the QRCode after it has been scanned.

Is displaying it in a < p > tag wrong?

The QR code is generated from a type string not taken from a database.

Am I required to have a database and  a script running with intervals that checks whether the QR code has been read, 
Am I assuming wrongly?

```
//in my file.ts
createCode() {
this.createdCode = this.qrData;
}
```

My code for displaying the scanned QR

```
//in my file.html
<ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
  <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Value: {{ createdCode}}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

If there are any relating questions that you have across please do refer me to it, as I'm not able to pin point over the few hours of looking trough.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just had to add span class which handles closing it.

```
<span class = 
            "closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;
       </span> 
         <ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
           <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <p>Value: {{ createdCode}}</p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
```

and in file.scss add the following to display the closing button.

```
    .closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: black;
}
```